# Xcode target run script build phase only seems to work from command line.

Tags: ios, iphone, command-line, xcode4, static-libraries

I have a static library target, that has a run script build phase to create a FAT library for the simulator and device into the same .a file.

When I run it from **Xcode (4.6.2)** there is a point in the build where the status is "running script" with a progress bar, but then in the designated directory there is no .a file.

When I run from the CLI with Xcode's build there is. Any ideas?

Here is my build script, it's a slightly modified standard one that's out there for this:

```
DEBUG_THIS_SCRIPT="false"
    if [ $DEBUG_THIS_SCRIPT = "true" ]
    then
    echo "########### TESTS #############"
    echo "Use the following variables when debugging this script; note that they may change on recursions"
    echo "BUILD_DIR = $BUILD_DIR"
    echo "BUILD_ROOT = $BUILD_ROOT"
    echo "CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR"
    echo "BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR = $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR"
    echo "CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR = $CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR"
    echo "TARGET_BUILD_DIR = $TARGET_BUILD_DIR"
    fi
    #####################[ part 1 ]##################
    # First, work out the BASESDK version number (NB: Apple ought to report this, but they hide it)
#    (incidental: searching for substrings in sh is a nightmare! Sob)
SDK_VERSION=$(echo ${SDK_NAME} | grep -o '.\{3\}$')
# Next, work out if we're in SIM or DEVICE
if [ ${PLATFORM_NAME} = "iphonesimulator" ]
then
OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD=iphoneos${SDK_VERSION}
else
OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD=iphonesimulator${SDK_VERSION}
fi
echo "XCode has selected SDK: ${PLATFORM_NAME} with version: ${SDK_VERSION} (although back-targetting: ${IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET})"
echo "...therefore, OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD = ${OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD}"
#
#####################[ end of part 1 ]##################
#####################[ part 2 ]##################
#
# IF this is the original invocation, invoke WHATEVER other builds are required
#
# Xcode is already building ONE target...
#
# ...but this is a LIBRARY, so Apple is wrong to set it to build just one.
# ...we need to build ALL targets
# ...we MUST NOT re-build the target that is ALREADY being built: Xcode WILL CRASH YOUR COMPUTER if you try this (infinite recursion!)
#
#
# So: build ONLY the missing platforms/configurations.
if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: I am NOT the root invocation, so I'm NOT going to recurse"
else
# CRITICAL:
# Prevent infinite recursion (Xcode sucks)
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"
echo "RECURSION: I am the root ... recursing all missing build targets NOW..."
echo "RECURSION: ...about to invoke: xcodebuild -configuration \"${CONFIGURATION}\" -target \"${TARGET_NAME}\" -sdk \"${OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD}\" ${ACTION} RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO"
xcodebuild -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -sdk "${OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD}" ${ACTION} RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
ACTION="build"
#Merge all platform binaries as a fat binary for each configurations.
# Calculate where the (multiple) built files are coming from:
CURRENTCONFIG_DEVICE_DIR=${SYMROOT}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos
CURRENTCONFIG_SIMULATOR_DIR=${SYMROOT}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator
echo "Taking device build from: ${CURRENTCONFIG_DEVICE_DIR}"
echo "Taking simulator build from: ${CURRENTCONFIG_SIMULATOR_DIR}"
CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR=${SYMROOT}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal
echo "...I will output a universal build to: ${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}"
# ... remove the products of previous runs of this script
#      NB: this directory is ONLY created by this script - it should be safe to delete!
rm -rf "${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}"
mkdir "${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}"
#
echo "lipo: for current configuration (${CONFIGURATION}) creating output file: ${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}"
lipo -create -output "${CREATING_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}" "${CURRENTCONFIG_DEVICE_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}" "${CURRENTCONFIG_SIMULATOR_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}"
fi
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've only seen the opposite.

Comment: Are you building both versions from the same place or is one project checked out elsewhere?

Comment: Both versions are from the same place.